# How to get content types available to a library using the REST API?

Tags: 2013, content-type, rest

Using the REST API, how would I go about obtaining the content types that are available in a specific library in SharePoint 2013?

I am aware that I can get the content types of items from a list, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rest source Endpoint URI structure

> http://_api/web/lists(listid)/contenttypes

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247038%28v=office.15%29.aspx) has some nice examples for using Rest in SharePoint 2013

Comment: Wow, didn't think it would be that easy.  My googling abilities were failing me apparently.  Thanks!